# Netbeans Startup option 'sun.java2d.opengl=true' not recognised

Tags: java, linux, opengl, netbeans-7

I'm trying to tweak the performance of Netbeans on a rather old PC I am using. I've followed some of the suggestions [here](http://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/) but the one regarding

> sun.java2d.opengl=true

fails, giving

> Unknown option -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true

I'm using Linux WattOS distro version 5, Java 1.7 and Netbeans 7.1.2. Has this option become obsolete now as the above page seems to refer to Java 5?

Are there additional steps I need to do to enable Netbeans to use openGL?

** Additional Info **

I realised that I should have used the option as

> -J-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true

Although now I get a crash when I try starting Netbeans now. I've submitted a crash report so I'll wait and see what happens and post the result here.

Comment: How are you passing the option to Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Check with

```
java -version
```

what version of java you're using. This extension is only supported in the Sun JVM, and quite a few distros come with OpenJDK by default.

Comment: Not it is the Sun JDK I'm using as I installed it manually. I don't even have Open Java installed.